# Is it possible to extend Array.prototype only for a specific type on typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, generics

I have the following prototype extension because I've been using a lot of `reduce`:

```
declare interface Array<T> {
    sum(): T;
}

Array.prototype.sum = function() {
    return this.reduce((acc, now) => acc + now, 0);
};
```

is it possible to force this extension to be typed only for `number`?

Comment: Since the function `sum` will be available for all arrays regardless, why is this a useful thing to do? Wouldn't it make more sense to derive from `Array` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I wrote the question, I ended up finding out how to do it:

```
declare interface Array<T> {
    sum(this: Array<number>): number;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'sum', {
    value: function(this: Array<number>): number {
        return this.reduce((acc, now) => acc + now, 0);
    },
});
```

It should also be noted that extending basic prototypes is usually not a good idea - in the event the base standard is changed to implement new functionality, there might be a conflict in your own code base. For this particular example on my particular codebase I feel it is fine, since `sum` is a fairly descriptive method name and very common along multiple languages, so a future standard will (probably) have a compatible implementation.

Comment: I didn't know about enumeration on javascript types so I did a bit of research, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my own answer.

Comment: FWIW, to match how other function-valued `Array.prototype` properties are configured, you'd add `writable: true, configurable: true` to that.

Comment: @Badashi Will a warning or error be raised if someone attempts to redefine the sum prototype method?